# Python plot window not closing after being called from a JavaScript script

Tags: javascript, matplotlib, plot, window

I have a JavaScript script (open_hist_w_user.js) spawns a python process and passes data to a python script (create_histogram.py). The Python script creates a histogram using the Matplotlib library and displays it. The problem is that even after calling plt.close('all'), the plot window does not close.

**Code:**

```
*javascript; open_hisr_w_user.js*
/**
 * This script is used to spawn a python process that generates a histogram for the specified username.
 * 
 * @param {string} username - The username for which the histogram is being generated.
 * 
 * @returns {ChildProcess} - The spawned python process.
 */

const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const username = 'some_username';
const pythonProcess = spawn('python', ['./create_histogram.py', username]);


python;create_histogram.py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import time

def create_histogram(username):
    """
    This function creates a histogram of data, with a specified number of bins and range, and displays it.

    Parameters
    ----------
    username : str
        The username for which the histogram is being generated.

    Returns
    -------
    None
    """
    plt.close('all')  # close any previous plot windows

    # plot the histogram
    plt.clf()  # clear the previous plot
    plt.hist([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], bins=3, range=(0, 5))
    plt.xlabel('Total')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.title(f'Histogram of Total Column for {username}')
    plt.show()  # show the plot
    time.sleep(5)  # wait for 5 seconds
    plt.close('all')  # close the plot window
if __name__ == "__main__":
    username = sys.argv[1]
    create_histogram(username)
```

I tried using plt.close('all') to close the plot window, but it did not work. I expected the plot window to close after some delay after the histogram was created. Before you ask why am I not just using a javascript script,I tried porting my code a few days ago using plotly and df3, but couldn't get it working; so here we are passing data through the console.
**Expected Result:**
*insert image of closed window here*

**Actual Result:**
[image: image of an unclosed plot]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
*javascript; open_hisr_w_user.js*
    /**
     * This script is used to spawn a python process that generates a histogram for the specified username.
     * 
     * @param {string} username - The username for which the histogram is being generated.
     * 
     * @returns {ChildProcess} - The spawned python process.
     */
    
    const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    const username = 'some_username';
    const pythonProcess = spawn('python', ['./create_histogram.py', username], {
      detached: true,
      stdio: ['ignore']
    });
    pythonProcess.unref();
```